# Rename multiple files in bash (1->11,2->12)

Tags: bash

I am trying to rename files which are in the schema A_B_x.csv, where x is in (1..10), what I want is to exactly have A_B_x+10.csv, e.g. if the file was A_B_1.csv I would like to have A_B_11.csv. I am pretty new to bash and have not found a solution, I tried:

```
for f in *.csv;
do 
   
    newname=`echo $f | sed 's/1.csv/11.csv/g'`;
    mv $f $newname;

done
```

which replaces all 1's with 11's, but I am not sure how to generalize it so it works for all numbers. Does someone has an idea?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do it quite simply with the bash builtin *Parameter Expansions*. You first trim the extension from the filename with `fn="${j%.csv}"`. Save the base filename without the number as `base="${j%_*}"`. Save the extension with `ext="${j##*.}"`, and finally isolate the number with `num="${fn##*_}"`

Now just add `10` to the number, `num=$((num+10))` and put the filename back together, `new="${base}_${num}.${ext}"` and then move `j` to `new`.

You can do that as:

```sh
for j in A_B*; do
    fn="${j%.csv}"       ## filename w/o extension
    base="${j%_*}"       ## base filename w/o number
    ext="${j##*.}"       ## save extension
    num="${fn##*_}"      ## isolate number

    num=$((num+10))      ## add 10 to number
    
    new="${base}_${num}.${ext}"     ## reconstitute filename w/new number
    
    echo "$j -> $new"    ## output result
    # mv "$j" "$new"     ## **Uncomment** to actually perform the move
done
```

Bash provides many, many useful parameter expansions, the set relevant to trimming from the front (beginning) and back (end) of a string are:

```sh
    ${var#pattern}      Strip shortest match of pattern from front of $var
    ${var##pattern}     Strip longest match of pattern from front of $var
    ${var%pattern}      Strip shortest match of pattern from back of $var
    ${var%%pattern}     Strip longest match of pattern from back of $var
```

(**note:** pattern can contain the normal globbing characters such as `'*'`)

**Example Use/Output**

If you had filenames `A_B_1.csv` to `A_B_5.csv` in the current directory, the result would be:

```
A_B_11.csv
A_B_12.csv
A_B_13.csv
A_B_14.csv
A_B_15.csv
```

Comment: Thank you Sir -- always a pleasure!

Answer (score 2):

Would you please try the following:

```
for f in *.csv; do
    num=$(( ${f//[^0-9]} + 10 ))
    mv "$f" "$(sed -E 's/([^0-9]+)[0-9]+(.+)/\1'"$num"'\2/' <<< "$f")"
done
```

- `${f//[^0-9]}` extracts digits from the variable `$f`
- `num=$(( ${f//[^0-9]} + 10 ))` assigns num to the digits + 10.
- "$(sed -E 's/([^0-9]+)[0-9]+(.+)/\1'"$num"'\2/' <<< "$f")" returns the
  file name with the number substituted by `$num`.

**[Alternative]**
If the perl `rename` command is available, you can also say:

```
rename 's/(\d+)/$& + 10/e' *.csv
```

Please note there are two different `rename` commands.

Answer (score 1):

You don't need `sed` for this (but of course you can use it). With only bash:

```sh
pre="${f%_*}"
tmp="${f##*_}"
num="${tmp%.csv}"
new="${pre}_$((num+10)).csv"
```